# How to auto send messages with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord,random,asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

async def auto_send():
    await send_msg('GOOD MORNING!')       
    await asyncio.sleep(28800)

async def send_msg(msg):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel('channel_id')
    await channel.send(msg)

client.loop.create_task(auto_send())
client.run(token)
```

The Error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<auto_send() done, defined at C:\Users\StudMuffin\Desktop\Things\Discord Bots\Youtube Channel YT\Youtube_get.py:31> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\StudMuffin\Desktop\Things\Discord Bots\Youtube Channel YT\Youtube_get.py", line 41, in auto_send
    await send_msg('GOOD MORNING!')
  File "C:\Users\StudMuffin\Desktop\Things\Discord Bots\Youtube Channel YT\Youtube_get.py", line 50, in send_msg
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
  File "C:\Users\StudMuffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1457, in fetch_channel
    data = await self.http.get_channel(channel_id)
  File "C:\Users\StudMuffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I do not understand the error. I am thinking that maybe by looping the message somehow It is doing something I do not realize and thus it does not work as I intend it to. Or is it the way I am looping this async func?

Comment: Where is `channel_id` defined?

Comment: I did define it I just didn't show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is due to the coroutines not being decorated by one of the needed discord.py decorators.

However, you may want to look into [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=) in this situation.

```py
@tasks.loop(hours=8.0)
async def auto_send():
    channel = await client.fetch_channel('channel_id')
    await channel.send('GOOD MORNING!')
```

Comment: It worked I forgot to add auto_send.start() in the event on_ready to start the loop and forgot to import tasks. In the end it all worked out :)